Depth of foundation for retaining wall next to basement wall
I am in the planning phase of building a retaining wall.  I did research and it says below the frost line.
However, where do you start counting?  The exposed height will be about but not exceed 32", but those 32" have dirt behind it.  A 14 foot (width) section has 6 feet of soil for gras dirt behind it at 32 inches high and behind that the basement wall. The remainder just retains soil.  There is about a 20 foot by 30 foot area of regular black soil and grass.
When you start digging down eventually you will hit sand.
If the frost line is 48 inches, and the wall in 32 inches high do you then only need to dig down 16 inches because it is has soil behind it?  Do you have to dig down 32 plus the 48 inches?
If the retaining wall is 1 foot thick and 32 inches high how much footer do I need?  Width and height?
If all you have to say is hire a contractor say nothing instead.
Note:  The local law says that a wall of 32 inches or less does not require a permit.

Frost line is measured down from the top of the ground.  With a retaining wall, it is the lowest point side.  Your local building department will know the exact requirements for the footing.  My guess is two times the width plus a foot depth(might be wrong).

Footing can typically either be designed based on wall weight and soil type (bearing capacity), or meet a prescriptive standard which will be based on local soils (rather, the worst-case local soils) similar to what crip659 describes.

@Ecnerwal  The top soil is all standard black soil with grass, below that is sand.  Does that help with the answer.
